Browswer can access Google Cloud Storage object, but proxy using the same URL can't
I have a Google Cloud Storage bucket.  I have put an image file in it named "bob.png".  I have connected it up with a Google Cloud CDN, and load balancer, etc. and am serving it in a subdomain "cloud-storage-manager-test" of my primary domain.
When I type http://cloud-storage-manager-test.<mydomain>.com/bob.png into a browser, I get the image of Bob.  It all seems to work.
However, I'm trying to go through a proxy, and when I do that, I get a 404 with the message:
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Error><Code>NoSuchKey</Code><Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message></Error>
I have verified using the logs for the CDN that the request that gets a 404 uses the exact same URL as the browser request.  But it gets a different answer.  The logs for the bucket don't show any issue.  They do not report returning some sort of error, which also seems mysterious.
I would guess that the CDN is not hooked up to the bucket correctly, but that doesn't explain how I get a good image from the browser.
Why?  How is this even possible?  I am at a loss.
Update
My proxy requires a bearer token in order to pass requests on.  It does not delete those headers. It doesn't really make sense to me that this would be an issue for an asset/bucket that has granted access to all users, but I decided to check it.
I just tried the following:
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer xyzzy" http://<the exact url>
This returned the following xml:
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Error><Code>AuthenticationRequired</Code><Message>Authentication required.</Message></Error>
As you can see, the above did not use an actual bearer token, just a standin.  When I attempted this with an actual bearer token, I successfully downloaded the image.
For the sake of clarity, I'll repeat that.  Using
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <actual bearer token for my proxy's use, not GCS>" http://<the exact url>
I was successful in downloading the asset.
This is, um, unexpected.  I imagine there is a header parser that does not like the format of the Authorization header and throws an exception that is kind of generic and does not usefully describe my situation.
I also tried the following, based on the thread linked to by Roopa M below:
curl -H 'Host: Nonsense.com' <the same url>
This successfully fetched the desired image, so bad/wrong host headers as suggested in another thread, do not seem to be the issue here.

Can you name which proxy server you are using? And as per this document
you must allow access to mentioned domains. Also check if you have entered correct file name as Cloud Storage is case sensitive.

The proxy server is the Sandstorm bridge proxy.    The file name is correct, it must be correct in order for the bare URL to work in the browser, right?  Or do I misunderstand?  I will check your link...

I have no ability to configure the proxy server.  I need to authenticate on my side of it with a Bearer token.   I consider it to do a bare HTTP request, and don't understand how it would be treated differently than a browser request.  Although the user agent is different.  Is this going to be significant?  Is there  a rule somewhere I can change?

Reading the document further, I note that most interaction with Google Cloud APIs directly is impossible through the Sandstorm proxy, since the Sandstorm proxy consumes the Authentication Bearer header, and does not handle it in a way that might pass a second Authentication Bearer token to the google cloud api.    Howefver, I did not think I was engaging  with a Google Cloud api, but just a content delivery network.  And the bucket allows public access by allUsers.  So no authentication should be necessary, right?

Can you check if the proxy is adding headers or modifying headers. Also check this thread

I have looked over the code for the proxy, and it doesn't seem that they are, and yet that's the only explanation that makes sense.  If there's some way to pull the complete headers out of Google Cloud, I don't know what it is.
